# Scroll view on a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I have a class which is inherited from UIViewController and has tableview and search view on it as follows:

```
//MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,
                                                                      UISearchBarDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@end
```

So I noticed that when I inherit the class from UITableViewController, I get the scroll view on the table view on its own, by that I mean I don't have to add any special code to have a scroll view on a table view.

Do I need to add any code to have a scroll view/scroll on table view when I use UIViewController? I am not able to see any scroll view on table.

May be a dumb question, but I haven't used UIViewController much.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to add any code to have a scroll view/scroll on table view
>   when I use UIViewController?

Yes, you need to add more code and all these `delegate`, `datasource`, `outlets`. Unless your `ViewController` needs more controls than a `UITableView` , it will be easier to use `UITableViewController`, since everything is already implemented

Comment: Can my UITableViewController hold a search bar? I guess it should be the main reason I didn't use it because I have a spinner which would be spinning while the results are being retrieved. This spinner shouldn't cover the search bar. As per my understanding if I use UITableViewController and place a search bar on it, the spinner would cover the entire view along with search bar. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you can add a Search Bar, what is the spinner, is that the `UIActivityIndicator`? if so then I guess its cleaner to add it programatically

Comment: Yes its UIActivityIndicator

Comment: Then you should be able to add it as a subview `[self.searchbar addSubview:activityIndicator];`

Comment: No I don't want it on search bar thats the reason am using UIViewController. With UIViewController I have a search bar and table view on it. So I add the activity indicator on table view as [self.tableView addSubview:activityIndicator] so it doesn't cover search bar.

Comment: With UITableViewController, I understand my search bar would be on the table view and if I add an indicator to the table view it might cover the search bar as well which I don't want to.

Comment: oh I understand now, you can also add it to the View and just center it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have two separate issues going on.

1. Laying out the views in some fixed relationship to each other
2. Populating a UITableView with enough data to make it scroll

For the first problem, you can layout the two elements (searchBar, tableView) inside of the parent view programatically, or you can use a xib (pronounced 'nib') or a storyboard to layout the views in relation to each other.
Laying them out programatically will probably be the easiest to get it functional AND actually understand how the elements fit together, but ultimately you should learn how to accomplish this layout step in a xib file, (probably should do it with AutoLayout too)

For the second problem, you need to implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol and the UITableViewDelegate protocol methods which feed your tableView everything it needs to populate the screen and give you the scrolling behavior you're not seeing. 
Make sure that `tableView` sets its dataSource and delegate to `self` within your instance of `MyClass`